# How to setup specific subdomain for rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, subdomain

I am trying to setup a subdomain for my site in rails. I followed to rails cast to do this. 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3?view=comments

I am having an issue. I want to state that for a specific static subdomain as a secondary homepage.

```
  constraints(Subdomain) do
    match '/' => 'static_pages#secondary_home'
  end

  root to: 'static_pages#home'
```

lib/subdomain.rb

```
class Subdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain.eql? "secondaryhome"
  end
end
```

so now I expect only secondaryhome.lvh.me:3000 to point to my secondary homepage. (lvh.me is and external domain that points to localhost) .However, any subdomain I have (for instance abc.lvh.me:3000) seems to be pointing to the secondary home, while i want it to default to my primary root. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

We've done the equivalent of this:

```
#config/routes.rb
constraints({ subdomain: "secondaryhome" }) do
    match '/' => 'static_pages#secondary_home'
end
```

This sets a route for `lvh.me:3000 with constraint { subdomain: "secondaryhome" }` - only that should work